# Get one of the solutions as Variable Value in Maxima

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

I want to create random variables for a way more complex program to read.

Some example code is:

```
a:random(20);
b:random(100);
[c]:solve(a = 2 * x + b, [x]);
tex(a);
tex(b);
tex(c);
```

however, the last line prints `x=5` instead of `5`.

is it somehow possible to get the value of the solutin in maxima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is that `solve` returns a list of equations such as `x = 5`, not just values such as `5`.

Of course the values are the right-hand sides of the equations. So you can do e.g.:

```
[c] : map(rhs,solve(a = 2 * x + b, [x]));
```